# Adding annotation to method in compile time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I was implementing CRUD operations for some of my entity and I was curios, is and how it possible to implement an annotation to add another annotation to some method in class. To clarify I will explain it by code.

```
@EnableCRUD(base="/tests", get="testGet")
class CrudTestResource{

    public List<String> testGet(String id){
         return new ArrayList();
    }

}
```

so my idea is, when the code is compiling the code should turn to:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tests")
class CrudTestResource{

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public List<String> testGet(@PathVariable String id){
         return new ArrayList();
    }

}
```

So any thoughts?

Comment: you need to create your own annotation processor

Comment: How? Do you have any tutorial, I tried but I faild.

Comment: Have you got a good solution? @navid_gh

Comment: No, unfortunately, annotation processing is to complex to be worthy of the time for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add annotation to `Class` at runtime.
You can use the utility class [`AnnotationUtil`](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/master/src/main/java/cn/xdean/jex/util/reflect/AnnotationUtil.java)

You can do

```
addAnnotation(CrudTestResource.class, createAnnotationFromMap(RestController.class, Collections.emptyMap()));
addAnnotation(CrudTestResource.class, createAnnotationFromMap(RequestMapping.class, Collections.singletonMap("value", "/tests")));
```

To group annotations as one, you can use [Annotation Aggregation](https://github.com/XDean/Deannotation/tree/master/aggregation). (may not stable)

Comment: I really prefer to not use external library, but thank you anyway

Comment: This is not 3rd lib. You can only copy `AnnotationUtil` into your project if only you follow the license.

Comment: Buy as I checked the code, it is for runtime. But I need compile time before spring boot starts

Comment: The "AnnotationUtil" link returns a 404. The new link is [this](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/master/src/main/java/cn/xdean/jex/reflect/AnnotationUtil.java)